# SQLAlchemy: Will session queries still work after a commit?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I just started in this SQLAlchemy ORM and I was wondering, if after calling a commit to a session, if you can still use that sesison to query and maybe even commit another time.

So, for example

```
session = Session()
session.add(Foo())
session.commit()
print session.query(Foo).first()
session.add(Bar())
session.commit()
```

Would all this code work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes.**
Long answer: Please read [Using the Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html) and also the [Managing Transactions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#managing-transactions) part of it.

Answer (score 6):

As @van already pointed out the answer is **yes**, however here is the explanation based on the [sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#managing-transactions):

> When the transactional state is completed after a rollback or commit (i.e. `session.rollback()` or `session.commit()`, the Session releases all Transaction and Connection resources, and goes back to the “begin” state, which will again invoke new Connection and Transaction objects as new requests to emit SQL statements are received.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def test_multi_commit(flask_app):
    session = flask_app.Session()
    try:
        foo = Foo()
        foo.id = 1
        foo.name = 'name'
        session.add(foo)
        session.flush()
        session.begin_nested()
        try:
            foo_obj = session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.id==1).first()
            foo_obj.name = 'i am change'
            # 1/0
            session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            session.rollback()
            raise
        # this will raise an exception and rollback all the change
        1/0
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        flask_app.logger.info(e)
        print(e)
        session.rollback()
```